# Why rails console autocomplete feature shows methods that an object doesn't have? How to truncate them form defined ones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-console

For example, this is a rails console session. I use `tab` key to get all available methods of `app`. But many of them is not possible to call:

```
irb(main):040:0> app.default
app.default                       app.default_executable=           app.default_locale                app.default_scoped?
app.default=                      app.default_external_encoding     app.default_locale=               app.default_scopes
app.default_action                app.default_external_encoding=    app.default_lockfile              app.default_scopes?
app.default_actions               app.default_form_builder          app.default_middleware_stack      app.default_separator
app.default_adapter               app.default_form_builder=         app.default_options               app.default_separator=
app.default_argv                  app.default_format                app.default_options=              app.default_sequence_name
app.default_argv=                 app.default_format=               app.default_port                  app.default_timezone
app.default_asset_host_protocol   app.default_format?               app.default_proc                  app.default_uri
app.default_asset_host_protocol=  app.default_formats               app.default_proc=                 app.default_url_options
app.default_charset               app.default_gem?                  app.default_regexp?               app.default_url_options=
app.default_charset=              app.default_gemfile               app.default_render                app.default_url_options?
app.default_dump_options          app.default_handlers              app.default_scope                 app.default_value
app.default_encoding              app.default_host                  app.default_scope=                app.defaults
app.default_engine                app.default_inspect               app.default_scoped
app.default_executable            app.default_load_options          app.default_scoped=

irb(main):043:0> app.default
NoMethodError: undefined method `default' for #ActionDispatch::Integration::Session:0x2e52208>
irb(main):042:0> app.default_lockfile
NoMethodError: undefined method `default_lockfile' for #ActionDispatch::Integration::Session:0x2e52208>
irb(main):041:0> app.default_locale
NoMethodError: undefined method `default_locale' for #ActionDispatch::Integration::Session:0x2e52208>
```

Console says the object has them, but if called they are suddenly undefined. Is this a bug? How to get only defined ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the rails console tries to be smart, but isn't. if you want to know which public methods to call just do `app.public_methods`